# Валидация на min количество вводимых чисел в input type=“number” на JS/jQuery для OS Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Помогите реализовать валидацию на min количество вводимых чисел в input type="number"?

Этот код ограничивает максимальное количество символов:

```
<input id="cardNumber" value="" type="text">
<input id="cardCode" value="" type="text">

if(isMobile.Android()){

    $('#cardNumber').attr('type', 'number').attr('data-max', '19').attr('min', '15');
    $('#cardCode').attr('type', 'number').attr('data-max', '3').attr('min', '3');

    $('input#cardNumber').keydown(function(){
        var max = $(this).data('max');
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if( keyCode!=8 && keyCode!=46 && this.value.length==max ) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
    });
    $('input#cardCode').keydown(function(){
        var max = $(this).data('max');
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if( keyCode!=8 && keyCode!=46 && this.value.length==max ) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
    });       

}
```

**UPD**

С этим кодом можно что-то реализовать? (сейчас не работает)

```
$('input#cardNumber').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        var val = this.value.trim();
        val.length < 15 ? this.setCustomValidity('Поле должно содержать не менее 15 символов') : this.setCustomValidity('');
    });

    $('input#cardCode').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        var val = this.value.trim();
        val.length < 3 ? this.setCustomValidity('Поле должно содержать не менее 3 символов') : this.setCustomValidity('');
    });
```

Тут полный код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/jnhmc4d1/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мой работающий код:

```
if(isMobile.Android()) {

    $('#acctNumber').mask('999999');
    $('#sumCheck').mask('99999');
    $('#cardNumber').attr('type', 'number').attr('data-max', '19').attr('min', '15');
    $('#cardCode').attr('type', 'number').attr('data-max', '3').attr('min', '3');

    $('input#cardNumber').keydown(function(){
        var max = $(this).data('max');
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if( keyCode!=8 && keyCode!=46 && this.value.length==max ) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
    });
    $('input#cardCode').keydown(function(){
        var max = $(this).data('max');
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if( keyCode!=8 && keyCode!=46 && this.value.length==max ) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
    });

    $('input#cardNumber').blur(function () {
        var val = this.value.trim();
        if(val.length < 15){
            $('<div class="error">Поле должно содержать не менее 15 символов</div>').appendTo('#errCard');
        }
    });
    $('input#cardNumber').focus(function () {
        $('#errCard').html('');
    });
    $('input#cardCode').blur(function () {
        var val = this.value.trim();
        if(val.length < 3){
            $('<div class="error">Поле должно содержать не менее 3 символов</div>').appendTo('#errCode');
        }
    });

    $('input#cardCode').focus(function () {
        $('#errCode').html('');
    });

}
```

Comment: Браво. Для полного фэншуя, я бы в цепочки объединил...

Comment: что значит "цепочки" ?

Comment: Правильнее сказать [несколько событий на один селект](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector)

Comment: Хотя [цепочки](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function) тоже можно. `$('#element').keyup(fn1).keypress(fn1).blur(fn2).change(fn3)`